# Google Map - getting error while loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my website, when I'm doing the design the google map was worked. After the hosting it shows an error:

> Oops! Something went wrong"

I tried to find the solution and found API key is missing. I had created a key with my personal Gmail account and added to footer place like below.

```js
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my api key=google-map" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But after that also it didn't work. below is my google map script in HTML and js.

```js
 //Google Map
 var latitude = $('#google-map').data('latitude')
 var longitude = $('#google-map').data('longitude')
 function initialize_map() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
  var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 14,
   scrollwheel: false,
   center: myLatlng
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'), mapOptions);
  var contentString = '';
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: '<div class="map-content"><ul class="address">' + $('.address').html() + '</ul></div>'
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatlng,
   map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize_map);
 
});
```

```html
<div id="google-map" class="wow fadeIn" data-latitude="13.0938666" data-longitude="80.202357" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="400ms"></div>
```

Comment: Did you activate the API for that key?

Comment: @geocodezip how can i do it?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Thanks. I have to register the api key with my hosting email. I will do i.